# LaTeX to plain text for e.g. generation of statistics

Tags: conversion, text-only

I would like to convert a large LaTeX project (i.e. spanning multiple files) into plain text. The purpose is generation of statistics, so representing mathematics is not an issue. In fact, all mathematics is ideally ignored.

I have found http://code.google.com/p/textricks/ but could not get it to run. It seems unfinished, but is exactly what I am looking for otherwise.

Comment: (if anyone knows a good tag, feel free to edit the question)

Comment: Done. [tag:plain-tex] was definitely wrong, which is about plain-TeX not plain-text files. I added the [tag:conversion] tag and created a new [tag:text-only] tag (which might be renamed)

Comment: I would compile the document into a PDF and then use `pdftotext` to convert it to a text file. This ensures that you are using the LaTeX output not the input which might differ. Of course, if you want to do statistics about the LaTeX *files* and not the *document* generated by it, then you need to convert the source instead.

Comment: The UK Tex FAQ lists some options for this: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=fmtconv+toascii

Comment: pdftotext is good enough for my purposes. I can post-process the file if needed. The question might still be interesting, though. Can it be done without going via PDF?

Comment: @Ben It can be done, if you willing to rewrite macros for all the commands to do nothing!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would compile the document into a PDF and then use `pdftotext` to convert it to a text file. You should [disable all hyphenation](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-hyphoff) and remove the page header (`\pagestyle{empty}`) to get only the raw text.
This ensures that you are using the LaTeX output not the input which might differ.

Of course, if you want to do statistics about the LaTeX files and not the document generated by it, then you need to convert the source instead. Stripping all macros is very difficult because (La)TeX is quite dynamic and macros can be redefined anyway (even by itself). A full correct stripping could only be implemented in (La)TeX itself because of this and then it is still very difficult. Some tools might simply remove all macros and brace arguments. This might be enough for your tasks.