# ASCII Output Rendering (man-page style)

Tags: conversion, output, output-driver, text-only

Is there a way to make LaTeX emit "man-page-like" ASCII output?

Including nice line-wrapping, indentation and headline-formatting.

Comment: Also try `troff`/`groff`.

Comment: Related question: [LaTeX to plain text for e.g. generation of statistics](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31859/3323). Also [Conversion from (La)TeX to plain text (UK TeX FAQ)](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=fmtconv+toascii) might be of interest.

Comment: Also related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19538/can-latex-be-persuaded-to-produce-text-output

Comment: @diabonas: UK TeX FAQ link has moved. New location is: [Conversion from (La)TeX to plain text (UK TeX FAQ)](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-toascii).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`dvi2tty`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/dvi2tty) is a first approximation to this.