# How do you get the plaintext from a rendered LaTeX document?

Tags: pdf, compiling, conversion, text-only

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LaTeX to plain text for e.g. generation of statistics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31859/latex-to-plain-text-for-e-g-generation-of-statistics)

I have my resume done up in LaTeX, which I usually publish as a pdf with pdfLaTeX.  However, one potential employer wants me to copy the contents of my resume into an HTML field as plaintext, rather than the pdf.

So, with that application in mind, how do I render just the plaintext of a LaTeX document?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  Perhaps [Convert LaTeX to HTML](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39309/convert-latex-to-html).

Comment: If you are running Linux or Mac OS, `pdftotext -raw <pdf-file>` does a pretty good job.

Comment: Why not select all the text in the pdf, copy and paste into your favorite editor, clean up as necessary. (Be sure to save what you paste into the job application so you can refer back to it accurately.)

Comment: You could try [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/).