# Are there any tools to perform text mining/analytics into a TeX document?

Tags: metadata

From two weeks I'm thinking about performing statistics in my LaTeX document to improve the way I write (and for curiosity). I would like to retrieve the distribution of words I'm using most, and other things like that. I know there are many tools to do that, but I'm not sure which is the easiest way to do it in my TeX document.

Comment: Hi! I think that there're no special tools to do this in a LaTeX file. There're tools for converting a LaTeX file to a plain-text file, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31859/latex-to-plain-text-for-e-g-generation-of-statistics and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530121/how-do-i-convert-latex-to-plain-text-ascii . Then you can use whatever statistical tool you wish ;) It seems to me that your question is basically a duplicate to the first link I provide. Tell me if you feel it the same, in which case we would mark them as duplicate.

Comment: No need to delete it I think.

Comment: @tohecz I've tried to follow the answer to the other question but this is not the thing I'm looking for... just for curiosity are you aware of some similar tool that I can run  whit the same modality of "a grammar check" from my TeX editor?

Comment: Well, as I said, I don't think that there's such a tool especially for LaTeX. If you have such a tool that works on files containing just text, you can update your question and be more specific, that you would like to use this tool on a LaTeX file. If you mention what operating system and what editor you use, the question would not be duplicate anymore I think, and it can get reopen ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I will work on it when I have a little bit of time!